# Why does R only save the last result when I run a for loop on anything?

Tags: r

```
test <- c(0,1,2,3,4,4,4)
for(i in test) {
   savethis <- c(i)
}
print(savethis)
```

This always outputs 4 no matter what I try. I want to save all the vector values into savethis.

Comment: Why not just `savethis<-test`?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you don't want to just copy vector `test`. If not, there are basically two ways to do what you want using `for` loops.

**One**, if you know the size of the output.

In the case you know that the output is, for instance, of the same size as the input, you can create an output vector beforehand and in the loop assign the values using standard indexing.

```
test <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4)

savethis <- numeric(length(test))    # Do this outside the loop

for(i in seq_along(test)) {
   savethis[i] <- test[i]
}
print(savethis)
```

**Another**, if you don't know the size of the output.

In this case you should create a vector of length zero outside the loop and extend that vector inside the loop

```
savethis <- NULL

for(i in test) {
   savethis <- c(savethis, i)
}
print(savethis)
```

Or using an index into `test`, like in the first example above.

```
savethis <- NULL

for(i in seq_along(test)) {
   savethis[i] <- test[i]
}
print(savethis)
```

Note that although this loop is using exactly the same instructions as the first, it works in a completely different way. Before the loop `length(savethis)` is zero. So the value `savethis[1]` does not exist, it is created the first time through the loop, then `savethis[2]`, etc.

If you do know the size of the output, **the first example above is always the best**. The other two force R to call memory management routines over and over again wasting processing time.